# Cropping a Greek Letter in mathmode

Tags: greek, letters, crop

My problem sounds simple, but I did not find something useful until now: I would like to "crop" a single letter in mathmode. Like for example, I just want to have the lower third of `\Omega`, i.e. the upper two third are just blank and the "cut" should be horizontal:

[image: cropped omega]

Comment: Is it important that the letter is really cropped, or would a white bar hiding the upper two thirds also work?

Comment: @marmot I think this doesn't really matter, this was also my first idea to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\clipbox` command from the `trimclip` package does this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\newcommand{\crop}[1]{\clipbox*{0pt -.5ex {\width} .7ex}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\crop{ABCDefgh$\Omega$}
\end{document}
```

The starred version of `\clipbox` leaves visible everything within the specified coordinates. To crop more, *decrease* the `.7ex`. To get precisely the lower third, replace it with `{.333\height}`.

The unstarred version of `\clipbox` clips (removes) everything left of the first x-coordinate, below the first y-coordinate, right of the second x, and above the second y.

Answer (score 6):

Really just for fun: a version that can partially hide parts of the text (or even other stuff).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newlength{\LineWidth}
\newcommand{\Crop}[3]
    {%
    \setlength{\LineWidth}{\heightof{#2}}
    \tikz[baseline=(Crop.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt](Crop){#2};
        \draw[-,white,opacity=#3,line width=#1*\LineWidth,transform
        canvas={yshift=-0.5*#1*\LineWidth}] (Crop.north west) -- (Crop.north east);
        }
    }   


\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\Crop{<p>}{<text>}{<o>}| with p denoting the percentage (or how much you
want to cover, starting from the top) and o the opacity.

\Crop{0.33}{$\Omega$}{1}

\Crop{0.5}{$\Omega$}{0.8}

\Crop{0.44}{\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{marmots are cute}}{0.7}
\end{document}
```

[image]